# Sybase to equivalent oracle

Tags: oracle

I am doing an insert operation in oracle

In sybase for instance(perl with sybase)

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO Custodian_New (Type, Id, User, TimeCreated, RcNumber) 
    values (1, %d, '%s', %d, '%s')", $dd, $Name, time(), $rc_num);
prints::(1, 10159, 'rrapak', 1301471663, '234')::Success
```

Insertion happens in sybase.In oracle the same query fails

```
Error:Cannot insert null values::

prints::(1, 10159, 'rrapak', 0, '234') ---Failure
```

The problem is time() value is not printed.
When i changed %d to %s,the value is getting printed.But the same error.Unable to insert null values

Comment: Please use the `{}` toolbar button to format source code. I was going to do it for you but I'm not a Perl guru and I wasn't sure about what was code and what wasn't :)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is actually related to Oracle and not Perl, you may want to have a look at this:

- http://www.club-oracle.com/articles/oracle-date-functions-184/

More specifically, the **SYSDATE and CURRENT_DATE** section.

Answer (score 0):

database column created as NOT NULL would do the trick.

Comment: @peter:THe column is set as not null.But i have given the values for insertion.Still it does not work